# Size property in paint() method different than size specified in CustomPainter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Here is the `code` first:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width1 = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    print(width1);
    return GestureDetector(
        child: Container(
      height: width1,
      width: width1,
      child: Stack(
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Child1(),
          Child2(),
          Child3(),
          //...
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}

class Child1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width2 = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    print(width2);
    return CustomPaint(
      painter: Painter1(),
      size: MediaQuery.of(context).size,
      //even trying to impose a child's width didn't work
      //      child:Container(
      //        width: width2,
      //          height: width2,
      //      )
    );
  }
}

class Painter1 extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final width3 = size.width;
    print(width3);//different than width1 and width2 !!
  }
//...
}
```

I am placing the widget `Test()` in a Column widget that takes the entire screen,and what I expect is that `width1=width2=width3` (i.e. I expected that the `paint()` method recieves the size same as specified for the corresponding `CustomPaint` class).

When I place this `Test()` widget in the `Column` directly,the expected behaviour is achieved.

However,when I wrap `Test()` with a `Padding()`,the `paint()` method then recieves a size smaller than `width1` (and `width1` stays equal to `width2`)

How can I make `paint()` recieve the size I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you wrap Test() with a Padding() the Canvas takes smaller size because the Padding takes up the remaining spaces.

> width1 and width2 stays the same because its the size from MediaQuery, which is your screen size.

I think the size you are getting in your paint() is your *width1 - padding*, If am not wrong.

Try to Align the child of your Container without adding padding.

Comment: You are right about the "width1-padding" thing, but what do you mean by aligning my widget?

Comment: Am not sure about the UI you want to achieve. I can help you if you could give me more input or a screenshot.